# What icon can I use to represent 'concept'?

Tags: icon

What sort of icon/graphic could represent 'concept'?

It would be very helpful as a place-holder when I am making basic sketches and notes.

Third Party Edit (from comments):

> hhajemi (OP): From my experience, I will normally try to clarify some key concepts in the areas of interest and the following discussions will be based/built/developed upon these concepts. Than the light bulb or CFL (thanks koiyu for sharing this) moment, I can use a "brick" or "jigsaw" piece to represent a concept. I believed that this is not original but I think it can serve the purpose. Thanks all for commenting.

Comment: what concept you want to represent??

Comment: @Jack: I'm assuming he means he wants to represent the concept of a concept.

Comment: @hhajmi - can you confirm?

Answer (score 7):

A *concept* can be an **idea**, in that case you can go for the regular **light bulb**.

It could also mean a **path**, a **structure**, maybe you could use a **blue print**, **drawing board**.

Comment: … or *tabula rasa*, which would be, well, blank. Rather dull for a symbol. +1 for a light bulb—if you want to be more 2010, draw a [CFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_fluorescent_lamp)!

Comment: LOVE the CFL idea! :-D

Comment: I think Honda has used the CFL in a commercial. It'll become more common as more localities ban incandescents.

Answer (score 2):

A comic strip style "thought bubble" may also be a way to express concept.